# Selecting multiple parameters from UDF or procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, hana, udf

I'm trying to compute multiple values and fetch them in a select clause. Whether its computed via UDF or procedure does not matter to me but I can't figure out how to do it in either way. I want to use it like this:

```
SELECT ID, BITMAP(ID) FROM X;
```

which then should return a table with columns `ID, Bitset1, Bitset2`. If possible it should be as performant as possible.

I have three versions currently (simplified, there's actual more computation):

**Table UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION TPCH.BITMAP(IN col BIGINT)
RETURNS table("BITSET1" bigint, "BITSET2" bigint)
AS BEGIN
    declare bitset1, bitset2 bigint;
    bitset1 = 1;
    bitset2 = 2;
    return select bitset1 as "BITSET1", bitset2 as "BITSET2" from sys.dummy;
END;
```

**Scalar UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION BITMAP(IN col BIGINT)
RETURNS bitset1 bigint, bitset2 bigint
AS BEGIN
    declare bitset1, bitset2 bigint;
    bitset1 = 1;
    bitset2 = 2;
END;
```

**Procedure**

```
create procedure BITMAP(in col BIGINT,
                        out bitsets table("BITSET1" bigint, "BITSET2" bigint))
as begin
    bitsets = select 1 as "BITSET1", 2 as "BITSET2" from sys.dummy;
end;
```

If I execute the select statement from above I get different exceptions:

For **TUDF**/**Procedure**: `cannot use procedure or table function in select projection column or cannot use window function w/o OVER: P_BITMAP`

For **SUDF**: `This user defined function has multiple outputs, but this usage requires a single output. Specify a single output.`

I figured out that for **SUDF** I can write it like this:

```
select ID, BITMAP(ID).bitset1, BITMAP(ID).bitset2 from X;
```

But this executes BITMAP(ID) twice which makes it slow. I want to fetch both values in one go.

Is this even possible to do in Hana or are there other options?

**EDIT 1:** for clarification the udfs and procedure usually depend on the input. I just return 1 and 2 in the example for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, in HANA 1 there exist the following limitation concerning user defined functions:

- table functions don't accept values of joined tables as input parameters. I.e. they cannot be used to implement a "lateral join"
- scalar functions will be called and executed for every instance occurring in the statement. Fetching multiple return parameters from equivalent calls will also call the function multiple times.
- table functions and procedures cannot be used in the projection list of a SELECT statement (not HANA specific)

To apply a user defined function to many values in parallel, HANA 2 provides multiple new features, e.g.

- `MAP_MERGE` function, to implement a map-reduce calling pattern
- deterministic user-defined functions, that cache results, so that sub-sequent calls can use the precomputed result

**add**: a good example for the MAP_MERGE feature in HANA 2 can be found here: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/01/sap-hana-2.0-sps-0-new-developer-features-database-development/

Comment: Hey Lars,  this is strange because the [help portal entry](http://help-legacy.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/76/5815cd7d214ed38c190dc2f570fe39/content.htm) states that TUDF can only be used in from clause and procedures need to be called with **CALL**. How does your _select_ statement look like?

Comment: Of course, it looks a bit different to your `SELECT ID, BITMAP(ID) FROM X;` call:
`SELECT * from BITMAP(1)`.

Comment: I'm benchmarking HANA1 so I do not have the option to use HANA2 but this feature would have been nice for HANA1 too :(

Comment: Why not using the current HANA version?

Comment: My method above are simplyfied, the two bitsets usually depend on the input. I just return 1 and 2 there cause I couldn't figure out how to fetch both. So the UDF should be executed for every ID in the table: `SELECT ID, (select * from BITMAP(ID)) FROM X;` but this isn't working (`field or table alias is not allowed as an input of table functions`).

If with version you mean HANA2, this is a research project and we want to test on HANA1 as its used more. But maybe we will try HANA2 too.

Comment: Correct, lateral joins with table functions are not supported. You could, however, use table input parameter to hand over a set of values. 
Sounds you really would benefit from the `MAP_MERGE` construct here.

Comment: Hmmm, I can't figure out how exactly to do it with _table input parameter_. Do you mean I should first do `select ID from X` and then pass this table to the UDF? I will need a table with the single entry then. Maybe you can give an example? If you add the relevant stuff we discussed (i.e. that its not possible in HANA1) I^ll mark it as solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: You're welcome. I put the summary of this discussion into the answer now.